# How to send sound of certain applications over chat programs (win OS)

Tags: audio, voip, volume

I have 5 requirements:

1. I want to send sounds that are output of other programs over voice chat programs(e.g. TeamSpeak, Skype etc.)
2. I only want to send the sounds of certain programs. Not all my system sounds
3. I must still be able to talk to them (mice input should still be used).
4. I still want to hear the sounds of what I send.
5. It must be a software solution.

My scenario:

I am playing LoL/DoTA/CoD/BF (whichever makes you happy), I am on Teamspeak with some friends. Something happens and I want to play a fitting sound (e.g from http://www.myinstants.com/). So I want to send the sound from my browser over the chat.

What I tried:

I installed CheVolume (http://www.chevolume.com/Infos.aspx). This is for handling output devices, not sound input.

I set Stereo Mix as my default communication device. This works mostly, but then I also send my game sounds over chat.

I have installed VB-AUDIO (http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Voicemeeter/). It can be useful, but it is not what I want. I get similar results as using Stereo Mix.

I installed Jack (http://jackaudio.org/) shame to say it is to technical for me.

I tryed using Virtual Audio Cable (http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm). Again, this only enables me to send all my system sounds.

Answer (score 0):

but Voicemeeter allows to do that:

1. Exactly : See [User Manual Case study #1](http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Voicemeeter/Voicemeeter_UserManual.pdf)
2. it is possible only if the application allow settings its playback device, then you will be able to route an application Voicemeeter virtual input or physical input through a VB-CABLE (Voicemeeter Banana version is better for that since it provide more I/O)
   3,4,5: of course.

Comment: Does same as  Stereo Mix. This sends all the sounds through the chat program. As in my case I only what to send additional sound from my browser

Comment: The link is dead.